# python mysql connector multi=true Continue even if an SQL error occurs

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I am using mysql connector python to connect to mysql and run multiple queries by setting multi=True. I am getting results. If there is sql error in any of the statements, the queries after the error are ignored. How do I use "--force" and continue even if an SQL error occurs

```
conn = MYSQL.MySQLConnection(user=sql_username,password=sql_password,host='127.0.0.1',database=sql_main_database,port=3306)
cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
try:
    results=cursor.execute("select now();SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now());select 'test';SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP();select 'aravinth';select yuu;show processlist;select 1",multi=True)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

count = 1

for result in results:
    if result.with_rows:

        print("Rows produced by statement '{}':".format(
        result.statement))
        print(result.fetchall())

    else:
         print("Number of rows affected by statement '{}': {}".format(
         result.statement, result.rowcount))

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

My output is

```
Rows produced by statement 'select now()':
[(datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 3, 13, 4, 54),)]
Rows produced by statement 'SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now())':
[(1591169694,)]
Rows produced by statement 'select 'test'':
[('test',)]
Rows produced by statement 'SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP()':
[(datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 3, 7, 34, 54),)]
Rows produced by statement 'select 'aravinth'':
[('aravinth',)]
1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'yuu' in 'field list'
end
```

I would like to continue executing all the queries even if any of the middle query fails.

Answer (score 0):

Because one of the intermediate queries throws an `Exception`, you cannot force the `try` block to continue executing from that point. What you can rather do is:

1. Declare  `results = []`
2. Run each query individually within its own `try-catch` block.
3. Append the result of each query to `results`.
4. Use `results` henceforth.

A sample code could be:

```py
# assume that queries is a list containing all queries
results = []
for query in queries:
    try:
        result = cursor.execute(query)
        results.append(result)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

for result in results:
    if result.with_rows:

        print("Rows produced by statement '{}':".format(
        result.statement))
        print(result.fetchall())
```

Comment: I wanted execute all the queries in a single shot

Comment: Have you seen the code of `cursor.execute(, multi=True)`? I guess internally must be using a string parser to generate queries, and then running `cursor.execute()` on top of each. Since you are batching all of these into one `try-catch` block, any one of them throwing an exception will lead to termination of `try` and subsequent execution of statements.